# How to download a page using Protractor

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, download, protractor

I have automated a website. Automatically opening a website, clicking on a link then selecting dropdowns Distrct,Talaka and Village, then selecting radio then entering number in a textbox then clicking on button then a dropdown appears then selecting from dropdown and finally clicking on a button. A popup opens and an aspx page opens.

Now I want to download the page which opens as pop-up. Kindly help me in the code.

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
it('should greet the named user', function() {
browser.get('https://mahabhulekh.maharashtra.gov.in/');
element(by.partialLinkText('अमरावती')).click();
browser.sleep('5000');
var allcount = element.all(by.options('v as t for (v,t) in 
names')).count();
expect(allcount).toEqual(6);

    element.all(by.options('v as t for (v,t) in 
names')).then(function(options) {    
    options[1].click();
    browser.sleep('5000');
    element(by.model("talCode")).$('[value="number:7"]').click();
    browser.sleep('5000');
element(by.model("vilCode")).$('[value="string:270400070038950000"]').click
();
    browser.sleep('5000');
    element(by.id('rbsryno')).click();
    browser.sleep('5000');
    element(by.model("sno")).sendKeys("10");
    browser.sleep('5000');
    element.all(by.partialButtonText('शोधा')).get(1).click();
    browser.sleep('5000');
    element(by.model("selectedSno")).$('[value="string:10"]').click();
    browser.sleep('5000');
    //element.all(by.partialButtonText("७/१२ पहा")).first().click();
    element.all(by.partialButtonText("७/१२ 
    पहा")).first().click().then(function () {

        // fill in the form here
        browser.sleep('10000');


 });

 });

 });




 });
```

Comment: Please, take a look at Page Object paradigm. Also take a look at ES6 (let/const, Class ...). What do you mean when say "download"? Protractor has a method `getPageSource()`.

Comment: I want to download it as PDF. If possible I want to send cont+p Keyboard command to the page then save it as PDF at the desired location.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save your document as PDF, you will exactly need to know which keys you need to hit and in which sequence.

So you are going to do something like:

```
action.sendKeys(keys.Control + "p").perform();
action.sendKeys(keys.Enter).perform();
```